# Publisher 2007 will open files in black and white

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-publisher

I have an old publisher file, it will open in the 2023 version in color mode.

But will open in the 2007 version in black-and-white mode.

What is the problem?

Comment: the problem is probably incompatible formats